# Autofac get service type inside ResolvedParameter valueAccessor

Tags: autofac

To be able to correctly resolve object for constructor parameter,
I need to know the type of actual service I am registering, since in my case I am registering multiple types from different assemblies.
I didn't find a way to access it via registration context, as actual activation is not a public property on it.
Example of registration below:

```
builder
                    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(_assemblies)
                    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IValidationPolicy<,>))
                    .WithParameters(new Parameter[]
                    {
                        new ResolvedParameter((p,c)=>p.Position==0,
                            (p, c) =>
                            {
                             //I need service type here
```

Am I missing something or it is Autofac limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 
`p.Member.DeclaringType` should do the trick.
`Member` property is a method/ctor that parameter is resolved for. `DeclaringType` property is a type where method/ctor is declared.